# mysql query to count

Tags: mysql

i am doing sql query to get values from db, db structure as follows...

**fcats**

```
| id | title  | section |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | test   | gd      |
+----+--------+---------+
```

**ftopics**

```
| id | title  | cat_id  |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | test1  | 1       |
+----+--------+---------+
```

**fposts**

```
| id | post  | topic_id |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | post  | 1        |
+----+-------+----------+
```

I want to get total number of topics and posts for given category and using following query...

```
SELECT id, title (SELECT count(id) FROM ftopics WHERE cat_id = id) AS total_topics FROM fcats WHERE section = "gd"
```

and it gives correct results for total topics but how can i get total number of posts for all categories, i am abit confused about, please help me to write this query. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.title,
    COUNT(f.id) + COUNT(p.id) AS total
FROM fcats t
LEFT OUTER JOIN ftopics f
    ON f.cat_id = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN fposts p
    ON p.cat_id = t.id
WHERE t.section = "gd"
GROUP BY t.id, t.title
```

Comment: but how could i get total number of posts for given section/category?

Comment: I think he is also looking for the number of `fposts` that match the `fcats`.  I haven't used mySQL in a while but I thought that it accepts a sub query in the `SELECT` statement that will return the count of columns that match.

Comment: @seoppc try my corrected code, i hope it works... i can not try

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.title,
COUNT(f.id) AS total_topics,
(SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM fposts WHERE topic_id = t.id) total_posts
FROM fcats t
INNER JOIN ftopics f
    ON f.cat_id = t.id

WHERE t.section = "gd"
GROUP BY t.id, t.title
```

not sure if this is the right syntax, updated the other answers code to try to answer your request for the two totals.